# How to open content box with hash #popup in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the basic HTML markup.

```
<a id="open" href="#popup">click</a>
<div id="popup">content</div>
```

I've made `<div id="popup">` hidden by default, and click on `<a id="open">` to open `<div id="popup">`.

Can I have it defaults to open if user entered the URL with the hash tag `#popup` i.e. `example.com/#popup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `display: none;` in your CSS:

```
#popup {
    display: none;
}
```

Then use any one of these in your JS:

```
$("#open").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#popup").toggle(); //When clicked, toggle visibility.
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    //You can detect a hash change like this
    //Since your href is set to #popup,
    //you can put the .toggle() in here as the hash will change when clicked.
    console.log("yolo");
});

if(window.location.hash == "#popup") {
    //If it is initialized with the hash #popup (ie. example.com#popup and Enter)
    //Use this
    console.log("yolo2");
    $("#popup").show();
}
```

Dat [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpFku/6/)